# How to measure an operation's duration in terminal, not in code

Tags: time, measure

For example, I need to do  "make " for some software.
I want to measurement how long this is going take.

Is there easy and accurate way to do so?

Comment: Use the `time` built-in. Example: `time make install`

Comment: Note that there is a `time` built-in and a more complete `/usr/bin/time` program.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the shell builtin `time`. Just write it in front of the usual command like: `time make`.